Quotient space metric well-defined-ness
Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and let $G$ be a group of isometries of $X$. Furthermore, let $G$ be properly discontinuous, meaning that for every point $x \in X$ there exists a neighbourhood of x $B = B(x,r) = \{y \in B \mid d(x,y) < r\}$ such that the images of $B$ under all isometries in $G$ are pairwise disjoint, i.e. for every $g, h \in G$ we have $g(B) \cap h(B) = \varnothing$.
Let's denote the orbit of a point $x$ as $[x]$, that is $[x] = \{g(x) \mid g \in G\}$. Let's also denote the quotient set of $X$ by $G$ as $X/G$, i.e. $X/G=\{[x] \mid x \in X\}$.
Statement: the map $d': X/G \times X/G → \mathbb{R}$ defined as $d'([x], [y]) = \min\{d(u,v) \mid u \in [x], v \in [y]\}$ for $x,y \in X$ is well defined, i.e. there exist $u_0 \in [x]$ and $v_0 \in [y]$ such that $d(u_0, v_0) = \min\{d(u,v) \mid u \in [x], v \in [y]\}$.
It's not difficult to see that we can fix either $u$ or $v$, so the minimum in question is equal to $\min\{d(u,y) \mid u \in [x]\}$.
Is the above mentioned statement true? If it is, then we can show that $d'$ is a metric on $X/G$; can we also show that if the statement is not true? Would $G$ being fixed-point free (no $g \in G$ other than identity has a fixed point) make it true?
I've only found answers concerning the special case $X=\mathbb{R}^2$, where it being properly discontinuous is sufficient for $d'$ to be well defined, but i'm interested in the general case for any metric space $(X,d)$.

Instead of $\min$ you should use $\inf$.

Yes this is true, if you fix your definitions and hypotheses somewhat.
Certainly $g(B) \cap h(B)$ is not empty when $g=h$. You perhaps wanted to specify that $g \ne h$. But actually it is enough to specify that the set $\{g \mid g(B) \cap B \ne \emptyset\}$ is a finite set. This is the ordinary meaning of proper discontinuity nowadays. Moreover, with this definition, one doesn't need any "fixed point free" assumption, which is a nice side benefit.
Once you have settled that issue, consider any $y \in X$, and consider the set
$$G(x,y,r/4) = \{g \in G \mid g(y) \in B(x,r/4)\}
$$
If this set is finite and nonempty then $d'([x],[y]) = \min_g d(x,g(y))$ exists and is positive if and only if $x$, $y$ are in different orbits.
To prove that set is finite, we assume it is nonempty, and we fix one $g_1$ in the set. Consider any other $g_2$ in the set. It follows that
$$d(g_1(y),g_2(y)) < r/2
$$
and so
\begin{align*}
d(x,g_2^{\vphantom{-1}} g_1^{-1}(x)) &\le d(x,g_1(y)) + d(g_1(y),g_2(y)) + \underbrace{d(g_2(y),g_2 g_1^{-1}(x))}_{= d(g_1(y),x)} \\
& < r/4 + r/2 + r/4 = r
\end{align*}
This shows there are only finitely many values for $g_2^{\vphantom{-1}} g_1^{-1}$. And since $g_1$ was fixed, there are only finitely many values of $g_2$.
So, what do we do if the set $G(x,y,r/4)$ is empty? Well, there's a useful additional hypothesis you can impose, namely that the metric space $X$ is proper, meaning that every closed ball in $X$ is compact. With that hypothesis, one can show that the "proper discontinuity" property holds for every radius about $x$, and so the set $G(x,y,t)$ is finite for every $t>0$.
Proper discontinuity for non-proper metric spaces is kind of a finicky property, and there may be counterexamples to what you want in that situation, but frankly I'm unsure.

Could you point me to how to show that with the property of being proper the proper discontinuity property holds for every radius about $x$?
What i tried is: let $x \in X$ be any point and let $r>0$ be any radius, we want to show that the open ball $B = {y \in X \mid d(x,y) < r}$ satisfies the condition that the set $P = {g \in G \mid g(B) \cap B \neq \varnothing }$ is finite.
Notice that the closed ball $D =  {y \in X \mid d(x,y) \leq r}$ is a superset of B, so the set $Q = {g \in G \mid g(D) \cap D \neq \varnothing }$ is a superset of P. Will continue in next comment.

If we now show that $Q$ is finite, we will know that $P$ is finite. But $Q$ is compact by assuming the space is proper. Let's choose any $y_0 \in D$, by proper discontinuity there exists an $r_0 > 0$ such that $B(y_0, r_0)$ satisfies ${g \mid g(B) \cap B \neq \varnothing}$ is finite. Let's then choose a $y_1 \in D \setminus B(y_0, r_0)$, again we get an $r_1$ such that .... We can cover the set $D$ with open balls $B(y_\alpha, r_\alpha)$ with indices $\alpha$. But D is compact, so we can choose a finite subcover WLOG $H = {B(y_0,r_0), B(y_1, r_1, \ldots, B(y_n, r_n)}$.

But I am now stuck on how to use this property to conclude that indeed the set $Q$ is finite. Any help would be appreciated.

You'll need a lemma: Assuming proper discontinuity, for any $x,y \in X$ there exists $r,s>0$ such that ${g \in G \mid B(x,r) \cap (g \cdot B(y,s))}$ is finite.

By $g \cdot B(y,s)$ you meant $g(B(y,s))$, right?

That's action dot notation. Just think of $g \cdot x=g(x)$. It doesn't particularly matter, but it does let $G \mapsto \text{Isom}(X)$ be a general action by a general group, rather than just a subgroup of $\text{Isom}(X)$.

Okay, so basically i'll choose any $y_0 \in D$ which gives an $r_0 > 0$ such that the set ... is finite. Let's label $B_0 = B(y_0,r_0)$. Then i'll cover the remaining $D \setminus B_0$ with open balls $C_{0k} = B(x_k,s)$ where for each $x_k$ I get a certain $s > 0$ such that the set ${g \mid B_0 \cap g(C_{0k})}$ is finite for each set $C_{0k}$.
Then I can choose a finite subcover of the remaining part of $D$ by WLOG ${C_{00}, C_{01}, C_{02}, \ldots, C_{0m}}$. Then repeat the process for the rest of $D$, choose a $B_1$ which yields sets $C_{1k}$ etc.
